# class defined variable can't be found by class function

Tags: c++, class, enums

"block.h"

```
enum BlockType
{
    BlockType_Default = 0,
    BlockType_Grass,
};

class Block
{
public:
    Block();
    ~Block();

    bool IsActive();
    void SetActive(bool activeParameter);
private:
    bool active;
    BlockType m_blockType;
};
```

"block.cpp"

```
#include "block.h"

Block::Block()
{
    m_blockType = BlockType_Grass;
    active = true;
}

Block::~Block()
{

}

bool Block::IsActive()
{

     return active;
}

void Block::SetActive(bool activeParameter)
{
    active = activeParameter;
}
```

Here is my class.  Now my problem is when I run the program and call the `IsActive();` function, I get an error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x0)` on the line that checks if `active` is true. From what I read is what is returned if the variable doesn't exists.  What is wrong with my code?

Here is where I call the function
main.cpp

```
Block* m_pBlocks[32][32][32];

void main()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 32; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 32; y++)
        {
            for(int z = 0; z < 32; z++)
            {
                printf("x:%d y:%d z:%d",x,y,z);
                if(m_pBlocks[x][y][z]->IsActive())
                {
                    //DisplayBlock
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `return active;`

Comment: You didn't paste the code that gets the error, your call to `IsActive`. Most likely, you're calling `IsActive` incorrectly, such as by dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. (And, as Chris pointed out, your horrible `IsActive` function can be rewritten as just `return active;`.)

Comment: We need all of the code leading up to `blockInstance->IsActive();`, not just the code from `block.h` & `block.cpp`...

Comment: @chris: +1 for "Unrelated, but return active;" - and make it `const`

Comment: my `isActive();` code was stupid...  I updated my original post to include implementation... btw I tried with the new `isActive();` function and still no good

Comment: Are you actually instantiating objects for the pointers in `m_pBlocks` to point to? If not, then this is your problem. If so, then please show the code where you do that so we can see if the issue is there.

Comment: As others have pointed out, the key question back to you is: how are the elements of m_pBlocks initialized?  The Block class is very simple, and the problem is more likely that you're calling through bogus pointers.

Comment: @TylerMcHenry Listen to that little voice in the back of your head. You know what the answer is going to be ;)

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
Block* m_pBlocks[32][32][32];
```

defines 32 x 32 x 32 NULL pointers. So when you try -> on those NULL pointers, it fails.

You either need to create blocks, or allocate them:

```
Block m_pBlocks[32][32][32];

Block* m_pBlocks[32][32][32];
m_pBlocks[x][y][z] = new Block;
```